# Extension of harmonic number to the real domain

Tags: special-functions

What is exactly the domain of validity of the identity:

```
Sum[1/(k + j - 1), {j, 1, i}] == HarmonicNumber[k - 1 + i] - HarmonicNumber[k - 1]
```

when `k` is a real number?

More generally, could I have a reference about the way `HarmonicNumber[x]` is calculated when `x` is not an `Integer`?

Answer (score 6):

As indicated [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html), `HarmonicNumber[x]` is the same as `EulerGamma + PolyGamma[x+1]`. So the more detailed remarks of [PolyGamma](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolyGamma.html) would apply. For a more mathematical explanation see also [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html). In the end it comes down to the [gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) which is defined as an integral.